# Request timeout - integrate third party library with codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm working on API integration InPost API Create shipment. I try to integrate third party library inpost with codeigniter 3 from GitHub.

```
https://github.com/imper86/php-inpost-api
```

I install this library via composer.

View:

```
        <?php echo form_open('inpost_controller/inpost_shipment_post'); ?>
                      <div class="form-group">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <?php echo form_close(); ?><!-- form end -->
```

Then I call in controller:

```
require FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Full code file  Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
require FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Imper86\PhpInpostApi\Enum\ServiceType;
use Imper86\PhpInpostApi\InpostApi;

class Inpost_controller extends Admin_Core_Controller
{

       public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
     /**
     * Create shipment Inpost Post
     */
    public function inpost_shipment_post()
    {                
      $token = 'xxxxx';
      $organizationId = 'xxxxx';
      $isSandbox = true;

      $api = new InpostApi($token, $isSandbox);

      $response = $api->organizations()->shipments()->post($organizationId, [
      'receiver' => [
        'name' => 'Marek Kowalczyk',
        'company_name' => 'Company name',
        'first_name' => 'Jan',
        'last_name' => 'Kowalski',
        'email' => 'test@inpost.pl',
        'phone' => '888888888',
        'address' => [
            'street' => 'Malborska',
            'building_number' => '130',
            'city' => 'Kraków',
            'post_code' => '30-624',
            'country_code' => 'PL',
        ],
    ],
    'sender' => [
        'name' => 'Marek Kowalczyk',
        'company_name' => 'Company name',
        'first_name' => 'Jan',
        'last_name' => 'Kowalski',
        'email' => 'test@inpost.pl',
        'phone' => '888888888',
    ],
    'parcels' => [
        ['template' => 'small'],
    ],
    'insurance' => [
        'amount' => 25,
        'currency' => 'PLN',
    ],
    'cod' => [
        'amount' => 12.50,
        'currency' => 'PLN',
    ],
    'custom_attributes' => [
        'sending_method' => 'parcel_locker',
        'target_point' => 'KRA012',
    ],
    'service' => ServiceType::INPOST_LOCKER_STANDARD,
    'reference' => 'Test',
    'external_customer_id' => '8877xxx',
]);

$shipmentData = json_decode($response->getBody()->__toString(), true);

while ($shipmentData['status'] !== 'confirmed') {
    sleep(1);
    $response = $api->shipments()->get($shipmentData['id']);
    $shipmentData = json_decode($response->getBody()->__toString(), true);
}

$labelResponse = $api->shipments()->label()->get($shipmentData['id'], [
    'format' => 'Pdf',
    'type' => 'A6',
]);

file_put_contents('/tmp/inpost_label.pdf', $labelResponse->getBody()->__toString());
    
}

}
```

When I post form, after 30 sec I get

> Error 500 Internal Error Server Request timeout

And now I'm not sure how to debug now. I enable error log in CI3  application/logs/  I open this file but I not see any error related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a defect, or missing http2 setup/cfg.
Since the header in https2 protocol has shorter header on packs.
Not sure doe
https://caniuse.com/http2 < short http2 (TLS, HTTPS) overview
https://factoryhr.medium.com/http-2-the-difference-between-http-1-1-benefits-and-how-to-use-it-38094fa0e95b < http2 as protocol overview in 5 min